# Multiple bibliographies with BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have a document with a bibliography and would like to print part of the bibliography twice. My *.tex file is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Some Text...~\cite{doc1}

Here I would like to print some of bibliography, with possibly the same style as the normal bibliography.
Let's say I'd like to show here doc1 and doc2, i.e. some cited and some uncited ones.

Some more text...
\bibliography{texFiles/bibliography}
\end{document}
```

My *.bib file is

```
@misc{doc1,
    url = "http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions",
}
@misc{doc2,
    url = "http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags",
}
@misc{doc3,
    url = "http://tex.stackexchange.com/users",
}
```

How can I do that? I tried to have a separate *.bib file with all the files that I like to print, but then I need to define `\nocite{*}` and all other documents get printed in the normal bibliography as well.

Note that I cannot use `biblatex`, since I have a *.bst file I have to follow.

Comment: See http://ctan.org/topic/bibtex-multi but note that whether a solution will work will depend in part on your `.bst`. As written, your MWE is not something anybody could compile to test since you don't say which style you are using but only that you have to use it. So it is difficult to say more specifically what might work. If you are required to follow a standard style, though, are you sure that splitting your bibliography in this way is permitted?

Comment: Yes, I even *have* to do that. The `.bst` file has more than 1000 lines, and I don't know how to read it. What could go wrong? Right now I even consider typing the first bibliography by hand and the second one in the normal way, but there has to be a more clever way to do this.

Comment: *Which* style? *Which* `.bst`? I would try [bibunits](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bibunits) as I think that's what I used before switching to `biblatex`. But I obviously cannot say if this will work with your style since I don't know what your style is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an example of how to use `bibunits`. It shows how to use different styles for different bibliographies but obviously you can use the same style instead. Note that these styles don't typeset the url so I've added authors to get things working:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibunits}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{doc1,
  author = {Author, A. N.},
  year = 1066,
    url = "http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions",
}
@misc{doc2,
  author = {Author, A. Nother},
  year = 1543,
     url = "http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags",
}
@misc{doc3,
  author = {Author, A. Third},
  year = 3012,
     url = "http://tex.stackexchange.com/users",
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{bibunit}[plain]
  Some Text...~\cite{doc1}

  Here I would like to print some of bibliography, with possibly the same style as the normal bibliography.
  Let's say I'd like to show here doc1 and doc2, i.e. some cited and some uncited ones.\nocite{doc2}
  \putbib[\jobname]
\end{bibunit}

\begin{bibunit}[alpha]
    Some more text\dots \cite{doc3}
    \putbib[\jobname]
\end{bibunit}

\end{document}
```

[image: Dual bibliographies]

To compile:

```
pdflatex <filename>.tex
bibtex bu1.aux
bibtex bu2.aux
pdflatex <filename>.tex
pdflatex <filename>.tex
```

or `latex` in place of `pdflatex` or whatever if you prefer.