# Separating academic and non-academic references: Illegal, another \bibdata command

Tags: bibtex, subdividing

I am trying to use a separate bib file for two kinds of references: academic (articles, journals, etc) and non-academic (websites, blogs, etc).

To separate them, I create a file `Academic.bib`:

```
@article{academic,
  journal = "Journal",
  title = "Title",
  author = "Author",
  year = "2014"
}
```

And another file `Non-academic.bib`:

```
@article{nonacademic,
  journal = "Journal",
  title = "Title",
  author = "Author",
  year = "2014"
}
```

However, if I try to reference them in my document, bibtex gives me the error

```
"Illegal, another \bibdata command".
```

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,abstracton,titlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Test document}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\cite{academic} \cite{nonacademic}

\appendix

\section{Bibliography}
  \label{sec:bibliography}

  \bibliographystyle{plain}

  \subsection{Academic}
  \bibliography{Academic}{}
  \bibliography{Academic,Non-academic}{}

  \subsection{Non-Academic}
  \bibliography{Non-academic}{}

\end{document}
```

How can I achieve the intended result?

Comment: See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172524/multiple-bibliographies-with-bibtex) on using multiple bibliographies in bibtex.

Comment: This is not really what I wanted, since both kinds of references can be found anywhere in the document. @Guido's answer worked well though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Bibtex solution:**

Multiple bibliographies are not possible with standard bibtex. However, the `multibib` package allows for it.

`multibib` offers the `\newcites{ac}{Academic}` commands that appends the proxies `ac` to standard bibliography commands, i.e., `\citeac`, `\nociteac`, `\bibliographystyleac` and `\bibliographyac`. The second argument is the heading of the bibliography. In this case a second `\newcites` is required, i.e., `\newcites{nac}{Non-academic}`

After running `latex`, one has to run  `bibtex` for each `\newcites`; in this cases:

```
bibtex ac
bibtex nac
```

and then latex two more times.

Here is a complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,abstracton,titlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{multibib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcites{ac}{Academic}
\newcites{nac}{Non-Academic}

\title{Test document}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\

\citeac{academic} \citenac{nonacademic}

\appendix


\section{Bibliography}
  \label{sec:bibliography}


\bibliographystyleac{plain}
  \bibliographyac{Academic}{}

\bibliographystylenac{plain}
  \bibliographynac{Non-academic}{}

\end{document}
```

producing:

[image]

**Biblatex Solution**

biblatex allows for multiple bibliographies. In this case one can define a special category `non` for non academic bibliographic entries, and then use the `category` and `notcategory` options of `\printbibliography`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,abstracton,titlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Academic.bib}
\addbibresource{Non-academic.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{non}
\addtocategory{non}{nonacademic}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\title{Test document}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\

\cite{academic} \cite{nonacademic}

\appendix


\section{Bibliography}
  \label{sec:bibliography}

\printbibliography[title=Academic,heading=subbibliography,notcategory=non]

\printbibliography[title={Non-Academic},heading=subbibliography,category=non]


\end{document}
```

[image]