# How can I include multiple sets of citations in something like a CV?

Tags: bibliographies, cv, currvita

The NIH Biosketch is a formal CV format. See:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/nih-biosketch-template/mtbcvhcmfpmw

The structure of the body of the Biosketch often include a several narrative sections, each with a paragraph followed by supporting publications (a bibliography). I can pre-format the citations using `\item...`, but I'd rather like to be able to do something like a `\nocite{...}` for each section and then render each section's bibliography based on that.

Any suggestions on approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bibunits` package is what I was looking for.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172530/12297